# Unable to present a modal view controller completely over the top of a tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm creating a tabbed iPhone application. When the application launches, if the user is not logged in, a modal view is supposed to be presented over the top of the tab bar controller (so it looks like this is the first screen). Upon login the modal view slides away to reveal the tab bar controller behind it.

Unfortunately when I call `[self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]` from inside my application delegate I can still see the tabs along the bottom of the screen. I need them covered.

Ironically when searching for a solution, I find most people are having the inverse problem.

I have noticed that if I *don't* set my window's rootViewController to the UITabBarController, only inserting its view as a subview of the window, then it works as expected, but Xcode complains about the lack of rootViewController. What's going on here?

My application delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method looks like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self registerDefaults];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[
        [self makeSellingListingsController],
        [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease], // stub
        [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease], // stub
        [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease]  // stub
    ];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    [self presentLogin]; // this doesn't cover the tabs, but it should

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)presentLogin
{
    [self.tabBarController presentViewController:[[[FLLoginViewController alloc]
                                                   initWithNibName:@"FLLoginViewController"
                                                   bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease]
                                        animated:NO
                                      completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening the login screen as modal if user is not logged in then make it rootcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't present it from the tab bar controller, but from the root controller in the first tab, in its viewDidAppear method. If you pass NO to the animation parameter, the modal screen will be the first thing you see when you start the app.

Comment: I get the same issue when I do this... the tabs are still visible. I must have something configured incorrectly.

Comment: @d11wtq, I don't know what to say. It works for me. You took the presentation out of the app delegate and moved it to the first view controller?